# TYPO3 extension: Preventing a record to be saved if the BE user input value was undesired?

Tags: typo3

I want to prevent a BE user from inputting undesired property values for records, let's say for the property IPv4. I wrote an evaluation class for this:

```
class IPv4Evaluation
{

    /**
     * @param string $value 
     * @param string $is_in
     * @param bool $set
     * @return string
     */
    public function evaluateFieldValue($value, $is_in, &$set)
    {
        if (!filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_IP)){
            $value = 'Fehlerhafte Eingabe (IPv4): .conf wird nicht angelegt';

            /** @var FlashMessage $message */
            $message = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Core\\Messaging\\FlashMessage',
            '.conf wird nicht angelegt',
            'Fehlerhafte Eingabe (IPv4):',
            \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Messaging\FlashMessage::ERROR, 
            TRUE 
            );

            /** @var $flashMessageService FlashMessageService */
            $flashMessageService = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(FlashMessageService::class);
            $flashMessageService->getMessageQueueByIdentifier()->enqueue($message);
            }
            return $value;
    }
}
```

But the only thing that it does while adding it to the field of the specific classe's TCA is to change the value to another value. I also use a flash message to warn the user that the inserted value is false. But i really need the record not to be saved in this situation. So in short: If the BE user does insert an undesired value and he wants to save it, the record will either not be created or not be saved, if he was just editing an existing record. How do i do this?

Comment: suggestion, Can you just try it by Ajax, ?

Comment: Ajax? Sry never heard of it. I'm new to TYPO3.

Comment: What exactly you want to do, can you clearify things? Ajax will automatically request in controller without refresh browser.

Comment: Everything should be handeled in the BE. Then a Scheduler task reads the repositories to create files for a server monitoring tool called icinga2. That's why i have a field called IPv4. Again: Everything should be handeled in the BE. TYPO3 is just a data input and collection tool to make it easier for the user to create the desired server monitoring files.

Comment: is it possible to show me your code?

Comment: What code do you want? The Scheduler task? The TCAs? The domain models?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161215/discussion-between-typo3-user-and-mondblut).